# How to stop a curl download started with nohup?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

How do I see and stop a `curl` download with the command being:

```
nohup curl -s -O https://urllink.com/file.txt &
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the PID of the curl session, then kill it

```
pgrep curl
kill -9 <pid>
```